# Removing Outliers 3SDs from the mean of a monoexponetial function in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning, outliers, exponential

I have a large data set that analyzes exercising subjects' oxygen consumption over time (x= Time, y = VO2). This data fits a monoexponential function.

Here is a brief, sample data frame:

'''

```
 VO2 <- c(11.71,9.84,17.96,18.87,14.58,13.38,5.89,20.28,20.03,31.17,22.07,30.29,29.08,32.89,29.01,29.21,32.42,25.47,30.51,37.86,23.48,40.27,36.25,19.34,36.53,35.19,22.45,30.23,3,19.48,25.35,22.74)
 Time <- c(0,2,27,29,31,33,39,77,80,94,99,131,133,134,135,149,167,170,177,178,183,184,192,222,239,241,244,245,250,251,255,256)
 DF <- data.frame(VO2,Time)
```

'''
[visual representation of the data -- * note that this data set is much smaller (and therefore might not fit a function as well) as the full data set.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JybFu.png)

I am somewhat new to R and very much not a mathematical expert. I would appreciate your help with the two goals of this data set.
Based on typical conventions of the laboratory I work in, this data should be fit to a monoexponential function

1. I would love some insight into fitting data to a function such as this. Note that I have many similar data sets (for different subjects) and need to fit a monoexponential function to each of them. It would be best if fit could be applied generically across my data sets.
2. Based on this monoexponential function, I would like to identify and remove any outlying points. Here I will define an outlier as any point >3 standard deviations from the mean of the monoexponential function.

So far, I have this (unsuccessful) code to fit a function to the above data. Not only does it not fit well, but I am also unable to create a smooth function.

'''

```
 fit <- lm(VO2~poly(Time,2,raw=TRUE))
 xx <- seq(1,250, length=32)
 plot(Time,VO2,pch=19,ylim=c(0,50))+
 lines(xx, predict(fit, data.frame(DF=xx)), col="red")
```

'''

Thank you to all the individuals who have commented and provided their valuable feedback. As I continue to learn and research, I will add to this post with successful/less successful attempts at the code for this process. Thank you for your knowledge, assistance and understanding.

Comment: Please take the time and effort to construct a small [mcve] that we can work with. What have you tried so far? Do you have code for fitting a monoexponential function (without worrying about outliers) that you can show us? (hint: `library(nlme); nlme(VO2 ~ SSasymp(Time, ...)`)

Comment: I don't see apologies as removing SO posting requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance and kind suggestions. I am currently new to R so having experts such as yourselves provide feedback is very helpful. Please refer to the updated post. I hope that this provides more valuable information

Comment: The maximum likelihood estimate for the exponential distribution rate parameter is the inverse of the mean of the samples. The probability of an exponential random variate being more than 3 times greater than the mean is approximately 0.05, so you should expect around 5% of your samples to be marked as outliers if you use the MLE.